# Why use ElasticSearch with Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have read a few articles recently on the combination of [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/) for storage and [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) for indexing/search. I feel like I'm missing something though. Why would you go this route as opposed to just [using mongo to index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/) the data? What benefits does elasticsearch bring and is it worth the added complexity?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

ElasticSearch implements a lot more features, such as custom splitting of text into words, custom stemming, facetted search and a whole lot more. While MongoDB's (rather simple) text search does some of this, it is not nearly as powerful as ElasticSearch.

If all you ever do is look for a single string in a single field, then MongoDB's normal query system will work excellently for that. If you need to look for words in multiple fields, then MongoDB's text search will work. If you need anything more than that, ElasticSearch is the way to go.

Answer (score 18):

A search engine and a database do some fundamentally different things. A good search engine (like ElasticSearch) supports far more elaborate and complex indexing, facets, highlighting etc. In the case of ElasticSearch, you also get your replies 'real-time'. On the other hand, a search engine doesn't return every single document that matches your query. Instead, it will score documents according to how much they match, and return the top scoring ones. When you query a database such as MongoDB, you should expect it to return **everything** that matches your query.

You **can** store the entire document in ElasticSearch, but it is usually not the optimal solution. Normally you will have it configured to return the document id's, which you use to fetch the document from a database. MongoDB is a database optimized for document based storage. this is why you hear about people using them together.

**edit:**

When this was posted, it matched the recommendations, but this may no longer be the case.

Comment: Can you give a use case ? i don't find it optimal solution to use both nosql together to achieve something special?

Comment: Here is a use case : https://blog.quarkslab.com/mongodb-vs-elasticsearch-the-quest-of-the-holy-performances.html

Answer (score 4):

Derick's answer pretty much nails it. The questions behind all this is:

What are the features you want to implement in your application?

If you rely on heavy searching capabilities in large chunks of text, ElasticSearch is probably a good thing to use. If you want to have a flexible datastore that can cope with complex ad-hoc queries, Mongo might be a good fit. If you have different requirements for a datastore, it is often a good thing to combine two tools instead of implementing all kind of workarounds to make it work with just one datastore.

> Choose the right tool for the job.